# Hudson taking long time

Tags: hudson

All,

I have a Hudson running fine, but I wanted to get exact similar setup in another test machine so I tried following steps:

1. Copied `hudson_home` from my current server to test server (Environment is identical to my current machine), with all jobs. Plugins and builds as well.
2. I restarted the Hudson and Tomcat but and its trying to access all of the config files under Hudson but its not able to fetch any data, trying to connect slaves and throwing some exceptions like this any advice is helpful

:

```
java.io.EOFException: unexpected stream termination
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.<init>(Channel.java:284)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:270)
        at hudson.slaves.CommandLauncher.launch(CommandLauncher.java:111)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:169)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Check the permissions on the folders. Are you using the same user to run Hudson? ...

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, try using the [Backup](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Backup+Plugin) plugin to backup your [Hudson](http://www.hudson-ci.org) configuration settings and restore them elsewhere.